# Model for Scoring Similarity of Activity?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

This is a very high level question.  I am looking for a technique or a model that can take web activity for people and be able to generate a score based on similarity.  So people with similar traffic patterns particularly ones that aren't common in the set as a whole would score incredibly higher.

I'm willing to do the research I just want to get pointed in the right direction.  Would cluster analysis be able to cluster people with similar activity together?

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a document analysis model like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis, where words are URLs and documents are the lists of URLs fetched by each person. As the article says, after building the LSA space "Documents and term vector representations can be clustered using traditional clustering algorithms like k-means using similarity measures like cosine"